# mov instruction fetches data from memory to memory in x86 assembly

Tags: assembly, memory, x86, stack, mov

I've disassembled a *x86 elf binary* that was making use of the C `scanf` function.
Here is the disassembled chunk of code related to `scanf` :

```
0x0804857a      89442404       mov dword [esp + 0x4], eax  
0x0804857e      c70424b28604.  mov dword [esp], 0x80486b2                                 
0x08048585      e8eafdffff     call sym.imp.scanf
```

Checking with `gdb`, the memory at the address `0x80486b2` contains the data `0x7325` ("**%s**" string in *ASCII* code).
So what this code apparently does is *pushing* `scanf` parameters in reverse order on the stack so as to call `scanf` with these two arguments.
This would have been typically coded in C as `scanf ("%s", &somevar);`

What I would have expected here given the assembly code is that the *32-bit representation of the **constant*** `0x80486b2` gets loaded *into the address* pointed to by the stack pointer ...
But rather, the `mov` instruction has loaded the *32-bit representation of **whatever was at the address*** `0x80486b2` *into the address* pointed to by the stack pointer ... Is that right ?

So what we basically get is that `mov` has just moved around data from a *memory location* to another *memory location*, which according to this [x86 assembly introduction](http://www.cs.virginia.edu/~evans/cs216/guides/x86.html) (among a plethora of others sources) is illicit (emphasis is mine):

> In cases where memory transfers are desired, the source memory
>   contents must ***first be loaded into a register***, then can be stored to
>   the destination memory address.

No register has been made use of here as intermediary.
How is that possible ?

Comment: Only in AT&T syntax is a bare number considered a memory operand (an absolute address).  You're using Intel syntax, specifically NASM from `ndisasm` it looks like.

Comment: @petercordes Could you expand your point a bit more ? I used gdb with the flag `architecture-flavor=Intel` actually. How can a simple syntax matter have an influence on the code ?

Comment: I assumed you were used to AT&T syntax, where `0x80486b2` is a memory operand, hence the question.  (In AT&T,  `$0x80486b2` is an immediate).  The machine code is a `mov r/m32, imm32`, but different syntaxes represent that instruction in different ways.

Comment: Maybe the GDB makes you think the actual `"%s"` was copied, because when you check stack content, it will automatically print the address value + content (for programmer convenience)? But the stack memory contains just that value `0x80486b2`, the string bytes `'%', 's', 0` don't reside in the memory pointed to by `esp`, they are still at `0x80486b2` address in memory.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> If I understand well, the `mov` instruction here loaded the 32-bit representation of whatever was at the address 0x80486b2 into the address pointed to by the stack pointer ... Is that right ?

No. The instruction

```
mov dword [esp], 0x80486b2
```

copies the immediate value `0x80486B2` to the address pointed to by the register `ESP`. This place is the first parameter passed to the `scanf` function.

> So what we basically get is that `mov` has just moved around data from a memory location to another memory location, [...]

No. The instruction moves an immediate 32-bit value to a memory location. The instruction's signature of the [MOV](http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/MOV.html) in this case is:

```
MOV r/m32, imm32        Move imm32 to r/m32.
```

The value `0x80486b2` is written to the DWORD memory address pointed to by the register ESP.

The instruction `mov dword [esp + 0x4], eax` does pass the second parameter from `EAX` to `scanf`.

Comment: In other words: it does not copy the value **at** the address to the stack, it copies the **address itself** (an immediate value) to the stack. So this is not a memory-to-memory copy. After all, `scanf` expects a pointer (address) as first argument.

Answer (score 3):

The instruction `mov dword [esp], 0x80486b2` moves the 32-bit immediate value 0x80486b2 into the 32-bit memory location pointed to by ESP.  If it moved the 32-bit value at stored the address 0x80486b2 into the destination, then it would be written as `mov dword [esp], dword [0x80486b2]`. However, this is not an allowed combination of operands for the MOV instruction.

Note that your disassembly is using NASM syntax.